# Unparsable date exception: string to java.sql.date

Tags: java

I have a problem with parsing a string to sql.date
This code works in my project only the first time, it will parse the date normally, but second time it throws exception.

I printed the date the function receives and it is the same format, for example 02.02.2016 was okey, I only changed month to 02.04.2016 and the exception was raised.

```
private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
private final String sqldateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"; 

public java.sql.Date changeDate(String date) {      
    String newDate = "";
    try {
        java.util.Date d = dateFormat.parse(date);
        dateFormat.applyPattern(sqldateFormat);
        newDate = dateFormat.format(d);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                   

    return java.sql.Date.valueOf(newDate);
}
```

Comment: Please show the whole exception (not in comments, by editing the question)

Comment: Why go from string to `java.util.Date` to string and then to `java.sql.Date`? You can create a `java.sql.Date` from the time value of a `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Consider what happens when you use `applyPattern` on the **field** `dateFormat`: you are changing the `dateFormat`, so a subsequent invocation of `changeDate` will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
private final SimpleDateFormat sqldateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

public java.sql.Date changeDate(String date) {      
    String newDate = "";
    try {
        java.util.Date d = dateFormat.parse(date);
        newDate = sqldateFormat.format(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                   
    return java.sql.Date.valueOf(newDate);
}
```

Because during the fisrt execution you are modifying the pattern of the `SimpleDateFormat` it won't be able to parse the second date.

`dateFormat.applyPattern(sqldateFormat);` will modify the pattern to `"yyyy-mm-dd"` and then parsing `02.04.2016` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you change pattern of `dateFormat`.
This will work:

```
private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
private final SimpleDateFormat sqlFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

public java.sql.Date changeDate(String date) {
    String newDate = "";
    try {
        java.util.Date d = dateFormat.parse(date);
        newDate = sqlFormat.format(d);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return java.sql.Date.valueOf(newDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this will work for the first run, but not for the second. Your problem is that you call `applyPattern()`, so it'll expect the new dates in sql date format only.

Here is a little better code:

```
private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
private final SimpleDateFormat sqlFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"); 

    public java.sql.Date changeDate(String date) {      

    String newDate = "";
    try {
        java.util.Date d = dateFormat.parse(date);
        newDate = sqlFormat.format(d);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                   

    return java.sql.Date.valueOf(newDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [`valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-).

If you have a [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and want a [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) (or [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)), use the [`Date(long date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date-long-) constructor:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Also, **don't** catch exceptions and continue execution without handling it (printing it is not handling it).

Meaning that your code should be:

```
private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");

public java.sql.Date changeDate(String date) {
    try {
        return new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.parse(date).getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date: " + date);
    }
}
```

**Warning:** [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is not thread-safe:

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.